# How to log call (SIP) requests in asterisk?

Tags: sip, asterisk, asteriskami

Is it possible to log SIP requests to a database in asterisk? I am interested in these details:

- timestamp
- SIP method
- status code
- source number/extension
- destination number/extension

I am pretty sure that it's possible to translate queue_log events to SIP requests and get the above information from it. However, as not every call goes through calling queues, this solution does not work for me.

Perhaps it's possible to achieve by using AMI? Or writing custom dialplan? Please share your thoughts on this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No way to do that.

Asterisk does not record sip messages unless you have sip debug turned on.

If you need control on message level, check out kamailio/opensips project.

Comment: Basically I want to provide a customer with their call events in realtime. The solution is done, but our current events do not contain information about the extension which picked up the call in case of incoming calls. You can only see the standard outside number. We use kamailio but I'm kind of afraid to go in there and start rewriting macros- don't wanna cause downtime on my employers infrastructure cause I am a total newbie regarding kamailio. That's why I wanted to solve this in a way which is unlikely to cause big trouble if anything goes wrong.

Comment: You can monitor calls either via dialplan or via ami events. But calls is not one sip message. Every call have much more then one message to setup. Kamailio deal with sip messages. Asterisk deal with calls and extensions transition. No way control any single message in asterisk. If you not confident, you have hire expert.

Answer (score 4):

I used to work for a customer who demanded very exhaustive real-time statistics. To get everything right, we had to combine the CDRs, CELs, and queue_logs. In the end this was a very complicated system but at the time being we didn't see another way to go. Well, we did but it wasn't feasible.

One of the simplest questions you can ask is: Who (A) called who (B) and who answered the call (C) in the end. If you can answer this question you can basically answer which customer (A), calls which extension (B) which may reflect the customer's interest. To find out where the workload occurred you have to have the final extension (C).

As simple as this sounds, it is very hard to do, depending on the customer's setup. If you have mixed technologies like ISDN for outbound calls, and SIP (asterisk/freeswitch) for inbound (in-company) calls, you might find that there's even no usable Call Detail Record at all.

Even for inbound SIP telephony, I can tell you that there are scenarios where just finding out the right A,B,C extensions is **very tough**!!! First, you have to know that Asterisk internally knows about two so called "legs", where two legs represent a bridge between two channels (please, correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not an expert here, but consider it as two endpoints talking to each other. In that terminology, there is no "initially called extension B". Also, the CEL and CDR don't relfect that. There're "dst" and "src" fields in a CDR but really the "channel" and "dstchannel" are of more value to you. The "dstchannel" sometimes look like "SIP/dialnumber@foobar", but only if your SIP accounts somehow relate to to the given number (extension=dialnumber). Note, that customers often don't care about the difference between an extension or a dialnumber, but in SIP you must care.

What really helps is if you use custom CDR variables. Configure your asterisk to use the "custom_cdr" driver for CDR logging and maybe "custom_cel" for CEL logging. Then you can set CDR variables in your dialplan and they are automatically written to the CDR/CEL backend logging facility (e.g. ODBC).

As a last point to think about: Consider a A, B, and C to be persons. Let A call B. Let B put A on hold and ask back at person C if she can take over due to her experience. Transfer the call from A<->B to A<->C (B hangs up). How many CDRs and how many CELs do you think you get from this? And how are the fields filled? In CDRs, this looks like A talked to B for the whole time. Only by looking at the CELs you'll notice that there was a TRANSFER event which gives you hint. (Sorry this if from my memory, it might be completely different now).

With this rather scary answer, I urge you to spend a very long time on **requirements engineering** rather than starting with asterisk and kamailio. Ask what use cases the customer wants to cover with your solution. Believe me, you cannot cover everything. Think about having a flexible data format for storing your statistics in. Think about document based databases like MongoDB.

If you want to start with pure Asterisk, you should use the AMI. Maybe have some custom process listening to the events, aggregate them and make them available through a cache, so you don't have to query the AMI and put load on the Asterisk.

I hope this helps, but probably you're trying to achieve something completely different. :)

Have fun.

Comment: This has given me some ideas. My initial thought was to pass on to the customer whatever information we use for billing. Basically, I was just sending them the events that the kamailio module acc puts into the database (that is the reason I chose the SIP-like event format). Only afterwards I found out that we do not log destination extension when the aforementioned customer is at the receiving end. The customer needs to know which extension picks up the call because they want to do some statistics on their employees and what not.

Comment: Anyways, the application is running already for some time- the only thing that is missing is the destination extension. That's why I am steering towards the "editing kamailio.cfg to gather that extra bit of information and editing dialplan to provide that info to kamailio" solution. I guess if I would start the project anew, I might do things differently E. g. design the events with AMI as the basis rather than kamailio acc

Comment: The point of this question was to find a simple hack to solve my mentioned problem. I thought that asterisk might be able to provide the SIP events in case of incoming calls and the rest of the cases would be covered by the already existing kamailio acc solution.

Comment: I have written a daemon in Node which builds Asterisk's model of current calls and connections (in memory, with AMI, real-time) to use in a client calls monitoring service (which is consumed by clients via WebSockets).

Actually, there is a whole theory with complexity like QED, with corresponding Feynman diagrams :-) It continue to develop and refine, despite of production use. Do you use Asterisk 11 or 13?

Comment: Hi @avesus, using node.js and the AMI was also one approach we had back in the days. For real-time presence information this was very effective. I've moved on and no longer write code for asterisk. I think we used an asterisk version even prior to 11 ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let's connect asterisk server using **asterisk -r**

then type the command  **sip set debug on**. You can find running logs and all sip request.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please clear one thing. Do you want only logs? If it is then follow the below steps,

1. open sip.conf and make sipdebug = yes so that sip messages are logged in debug file
2. open asterisk.conf and check for astlogdir. it will give you debug file location. If you want you can change the location.
3. open logger.conf and add log types whatever log you want to have under debug =>
   e.g. debug =>  notice,warning,error,verbose,dtmf
4. Restart the asterisk process to make this changes effective.

Apart from this if I need to store extra data or if I want to do something with the call then I write my own dial plan with custom function and I use mysql database to store my required data. If you want to write your own application then asterisk and asterisk-addon need to be installed on your system and start writing your own application under asterisk-addon/apps dir and place the shared library in lib or lib64, depending your system type. Don't forget to restart asterisk after making any type of changes. Let me know if I am able to clear your doubt.

Comment: No, I am interested in SIP-like call events (described in the question) so that I can provide realtime call data to a customer. Logs would most likely be unsuitable in this case

Comment: Actually I write my own asterisk application depending on the requirement, so I generate my own cdr. I don't know your call asterisk dial plan or scenario. But if you want then can tell you example scenario what I do if I need to make a outbound call and log the details.

Comment: but CDR is not the same as call events (unless I don't understand the concept). I could very well send CDR to the customer after it's generated- the problem with this is that CDR are generated after the call session has ended. In other words, the customer would not get the details of her call in realtime. That's why I wanna send SIP style events to the customer so that they can build realtime applications based on these events. Example session: |t0| INVITE 180 (ring) |t1| INVITE 180 (ring) |t2| INVITE 200 (answer) |t3| BYE 200 (hangup)

Comment: Then you need to make change in asterisk implementation file. You can check asterisk-<version>/main/channel.c and asterisk-<version>/channels/chan_sip.c file. You need to go through these and related files once to understand how asterisk handling incoming sip messages.If I am not wrong basically you want to log every sip intermediate states per session.

Comment: Yes, I wanna log "sip intermediate states per session". I'm gonna use kamailio for that.